# tailing log file and only showing a specific value

Tags: regex, shell, unix, tail

I'm currently tailing a log fine using

```
tail -f my_log_file
```

each line added in the log file looks like:

```
blaaa blaaa something blaa blaa response_time 100ms blaa blaaaaa
blaaa blaaa something blaa blaa response_time 150ms blaa blaaaaa
blaaa blaaa something blaa blaa response_time 90ms blaa blaaaaa
```

what i would really like is to be able to tail this log file, but only display

```
response_time 100ms
response_time 150ms
response_time 90ms
```

Is there a way to do this with "tail" ?
Thanks!

Comment: does `tail -f my_log_file | grep response_time | cut -d' ' -f7,8` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the output of `tail` through `sed` and `grep` to filter it. Try:

```
tail -f my_log_file | sed -e 's/.*\(response_time \S\+\).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: would it also be possible to aggregate these values and create an average ?

Comment: You might want to use option `-u` for `sed` to make it unbuffered output.  That `tail -f` will probably make slow output, so buffering it will not be as nice.

Comment: @Alfe: From my experience, `tail` flushes it's output when it reads EOF.

Comment: Yeah, `tail` does, and `sed` does also if and only if you ask it to :)  The problem is that `tail` will never _close_ its output when acting with option `-f` (and thus nudge `sed` to flush everything).  So better tell `sed` to flush regularly.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
tail -f my_log_file | grep -o 'response_time [0-9]+ms'
```

Comment: You might want to add option `--line-buffered` to the `grep` to avoid delays in the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -u 's/.* \(response_time [0-9]\{1,\}ms\) .*/\1/" my_log_file
```

-u is a stream version of Input/Output. **Work until first EOF** (so a script using `echo >> my_log_file` add to end of file but with an EOF at each action and thus stop the sed, tail will wait an interruption from outside)